# When the document size is larger than memory in Solr?

Tags: java, memory, solr, lucene, search-engine

I have 3gb document size and 1.5gb ram. When I start an instance of Solr, it automatically starts to consume 1gb memory. And then I enter the curl command that updates document from console. After a few seconds the Solr instance fill all memory and starts to consume cpu. The update process never finish and cpu usage increases in time. Is there any way to handle this problem?

My Solr schema is in here: https://github.com/buremba/mbslave/tree/master/solr

Answer (score 1):

How many documents do you have?  Or is this one 3gb document?

If you have more than one doc, you can add them in batches and commit after each batch.  Each batch could be less than 100mb.  In that way you can manage the heap size.

Also, to get around the immediate issue, you can increase the os virtual memory and use higher java heap size (-Xmx of 4gb).

Comment: Unfortunaly, I have only one document. I can only seperate 2gb-500mb-500mb. And I can't increase memory at this time. :/ Is this an expected behavior of Solr?

Comment: I think you are just running into various physical resource and design limitations.  The document needs to be sent from disk to the jetty server, which then deserializes the doc and sends to Solr servlet.  If you are using csv format, then the xml doc need not be parsed at least (what is the doc format?).  What analyzer are you using?  Also, interested to know what the use case is (as any/all search hits return the same doc id).